# Solution of a system of differential equations with a correction factor varying over time

Tags: differential-equations, conditional

Dear Mathematica users,

I am trying to solve a system of equations of first order and time depedent. The system has 5 equations, one for every variable which varies over time. At the moment I am using NDSolve and every thing works fine. However, now my system got complicated. I do have to correct it by empliying a correction factor when my temperature increases above certain value. The temperature is one of the variables which depends of the time and the correction factor affects only to some parameters of certain equations. This correction factor changes from 1 to 10E-45. My fundamental problem is that I do not how to introduce this correction meanwhile the calculation is being made. I do not know whether I should use conditional and in the way a must use them. The solution would be some subroutine in which the system is solve for every time step and termperature is compare with the critical value. Thus the NDSolve can either continue and keep correction=1 or change the value to 10E-45.

Does anybody have any idea about how to solve this programming problem?

Thank you very much in advance.
Regards.

Dear StackExchange Mathematica comunity,
First of all, sorry for not introducing my system of equations in the question with the value of parameters. I thought it was going to be a lot. Secondly, sorry for introducing it in an answer and in a bad way. I do have my equations copied from Math as Plain Text and pasted in a Word file. From there one can copy them and write paste it in Math. It does work. So I did paste it again here in the same format.

Thank you very much again in advance (I do think that WhenEvent will work out, but please tell more possibilities, so I could learn about this fantastic program)

```
    (*Laser amplitude calculation*)
    fluence=20*10^-3 *10000/1(*/J m-2*);
    lspot=0.0001(*Laser spot diameter/ m*);
    larea=(lspot*lspot/4)*Pi;
    energy=fluence*(lspot*lspot/4)*Pi;(*/J*)
    pulseduration=5*10^-9;(*/s*)
    peakintensity=energy/pulseduration ;
    intensity=fluence/pulseduration;
    lim1=0;
    lim2=50*10^-9;
    lim3=100*10^-9;
    μ1=8*10^-9;σ1=(4*10^-9)/2.3528;y5=0;
    f[y_,r1_]:=y5+r1*(E^(( -(y-μ1)^2/(2 σ1^2)))) /(σ1 Sqrt[2 π]);
    res=\!\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(lim1\), \(lim2\)]\(\((y5 + r1*
    \*FractionBox[\(
    \*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), 
    FractionBox[\(\(\ \)\(-
    \*SuperscriptBox[\((y - μ1)\), \(2\)]\)\), \(2\ 
    \*SuperscriptBox[\(σ1\), \(2\)]\)]]\(\ \)\), \(σ1 
    \*SqrtBox[\(2\ π\)]\)])\) \[DifferentialD]y\)\);
    RES=NSolve[res==intensity,r1]
    a2=r1/.RES[[1]];
    a3=a2/(pulseduration*(lspot*lspot/4)*Pi);
    a4=fluence/pulseduration;


    (*Gaussian laser pulse*)
    u[t_]:=y5+a2*(E^(( -(t-μ1)^2/(2 σ1^2)))) /(σ1 Sqrt[2 π]);
    a5=1.602177*10^2;
    (*Voltage function*)
    del=10*10^-9;v=5000;τ3=1*10^-9;
    z[y_]:=v-E^((- y+del)/τ3);
    j[y_]:=1/(1+E^((- y+del)/τ3))

    (*Parameters*)
    p1=8.05*(1.602177*10^-19)/1;
    p2=7.82*(1.602177*10^-19)/1(*7.2*);
    n1=3.466*(1.602177*10^-19)/1;
    n2=2*3.6789*(1.602177*10^-19)/1;
    temp=298;
    σ01=(9.9*10^-18)*1/10000;
    σ10=(2*10^-18)*1/10000;
    σ1n=(2*10^-18)*1/10000;
    τ1=(1*10^-9-3*10^-9)/(1+E^((t-4.44*10^-9)/10^-15))+3*10^-9;
    τ2=3*10^-9;
    ϕs1=(1*10^-9)/(3*10^-9);
    f=4.5;
    density=1.44*1000000/1000;
    kn1=7.5*10^10;
    k11=7*10^9;
    k1n=1*10^11;
    k20=1.5*10^11;
    fcluster=0.85;
    dip=6;(*Range of pooling process*)
    h=6.626*10^-34;
    υ=(3*10^8)/(337*10^-9)(*Laser wavelength / m*);
    time=1*10^-9;
    b=1.38066*10^-23;
    pansion=4;
    conc=0.000005/1*6.23*10^23*10^-6
    etial=temp*b*f *conc(*Internal energy*)

    (*k thermic*)
    k[m_]:=9*10^15*Exp[(n1-p2)/(b*m)];

    na=1 (*6.23*10^23*);
    matrixspot=0.0015^2*Pi;
    areaspot=(lspot*lspot/4)*Pi;
    ini=3.46*10^15(*conc*areaspot/matrixspot//(2.55744*10^5)/(360*10^2*10^-27) 0.05*10^-6*6.23*10^23*areaspot/matrixspot*)

(*Expansion Correction*)
c=6.982;
b1=1.489;
b2=3.036;
c1=1.5;
c2=0.4282;
lspot=0.0001;
ddistance=10^-7;
equis=ddistance/lspot;
mfactor=c-b1*Exp[-c1*equis]-b2*Exp[-c2*equis];
γ=1.05;
tau=(4*10^-9)/2.3528;

correction=(1+γ/(γ-1)*mfactor^2)^(-γ/(γ-1));
corrt[t_]:=Piecewise[{{1,t<4.43*10^-9},{correction,t>=4.43*10^-9}}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please include a simple version (say, one equation) of your problem, including the correction factor, so that readers can make concrete suggestions.

Comment: If you are using MMA of v.9 or higher, I can suggest looking up `WhenEvent` in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear where the correction factor is to be applied in the OP's code, or at least it is on a cursory reading of the code.  The problem in the *title* is as easy as defining a function and including it as a coefficient in the differential equation:

```
correctionfactor[t_] := ...
NDSolve[{x'[t] == correctionfactor[t] x[t]...
```

The general problem as described in the *text* of the question, in which the coefficient is **discontinuous**, needs special treatment for `NDSolve` to efficiently handle the discontinuities; a solution can be implemented with either `Piecewise` or `WhenEvent`.

`Piecewise` changes the value of `correctionfactor` whenever the temperature `T` crosses the `criticaltemp`. Here the ODE defines `temp[t]` as a monotonic function, so this happens at most once.

```
Clear[correctionfactor];
criticaltemp = 1;
correctionfactor[T_] := Piecewise[{{1, T < criticaltemp}}, 10^-1];
ode = {temp'[t] == correctionfactor[temp[t]] temp[t], temp[0] == 0.1};
{sol} = NDSolve[ode, temp, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[temp[t] /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This `WhenEvent` changes the `correctionfactor` only when the temperature *increases* past the `criticaltemp`.  Since `temp[t]` is monotonic, this is equivalent to the first method.

```
Clear[correctionfactor];
criticaltemp = 1;
ode = {temp'[t] == correctionfactor[t] temp[t], temp[0] == 0.1};
{sol} = NDSolve[{ode,
    correctionfactor[0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[temp[t] > criticaltemp, correctionfactor[t] -> 10^-1]},
   temp, {t, 0, 10},
   DiscreteVariables -> {correctionfactor}];

Plot[temp[t] /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below the ODE leads to an oscillating `temp[t]`.  With `Piecewise` we see the discontinuity in the derivative every time the temperature crosses (whether increasing or decreasing) the `criticaltemp`.

```
Clear[correctionfactor];
criticaltemp = 1;
correctionfactor[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, t < criticaltemp}}, 10^-45];
ode = {temp'[t] == -correctionfactor[temp[t]] temp[t] + 2 Cos[t], temp[0] == 0.2};
{sol} = NDSolve[ode, temp, {t, 0, 25}];

Plot[temp[t] /. sol // Evaluate, Evaluate@Flatten[{t, temp["Domain"] /. sol}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the single `WhenEvent` changes the `correctionfactor` to `10^-45` and never changes it back:

```
Clear[correctionfactor];
criticaltemp = 1;
ode = {temp'[t] == -correctionfactor[t] temp[t] + 2 Cos[t], temp[0] == 0.1};
{sol} = NDSolve[{ode,
    correctionfactor[0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[temp[t] > criticaltemp, correctionfactor[t] -> 10^-45]},
   temp, {t, 0, 25},
   DiscreteVariables -> {correctionfactor}];

Plot[temp[t] /. sol // Evaluate, Evaluate@Flatten[{t, temp["Domain"] /. sol}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the same behavior as `Piecewise`, we need a second `WhenEvent`.

```
Clear[correctionfactor];
criticaltemp = 1;
ode = {temp'[t] == -correctionfactor[t] temp[t] + 2 Cos[t], temp[0] == 0.1};
{sol} = NDSolve[{ode,
    correctionfactor[0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[temp[t] > criticaltemp, correctionfactor[t] -> 10^-45], 
    WhenEvent[temp[t] < criticaltemp, correctionfactor[t] -> 1]},
   temp, {t, 0, 25},
   DiscreteVariables -> {correctionfactor}];

Plot[temp[t] /. sol // Evaluate, Evaluate@Flatten[{t, temp["Domain"] /. sol}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which of the last two `WhenEvent` models is appropriate depends entirely on the problem being modeled.  [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) has options that makes building a robust model somewhat easier in some cases than `Piecewise`.

**Caveat**:  Note that the swing from `1` to `10^-45` is quite large at ordinary `MachinePrecision`, which has slightly less than 16 digits of precision.  It might lead to problems with the numerics.  See also [`$MachineEpsilon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineEpsilon.html).

Comment: Dear Michael E2,

Comment: First of all, thank´s a lot for your comment. I will try this way write now. Besides, I did change the equations so, you can see where the correction must be applied. Only to some constants (K20,K11,K10).Secondly I would like to ask you for something more. I should repeat the calculation several time for different ddistance values (see Expansion correction in the text) and then I should sum up all the valued i go from every integration. How can I do this? In other programming codes one can used Do, but in Mathematica this does not work out. What do you recommend me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dear Michael E2, I have implemented piecewise for my correction factor and for two other parameters that change over time. Now my problem is another. If I set a StartingStepSize lower than te time (10E-9) where my T=450, the program stops and returns:

Comment: NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 1.034911650603046`*^-8, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

Comment: Do you Know how can I solve this?

Comment: @RKdifferential First, please excuse me for pointing out that your system is quite complicated and it would take me considerable time to understand it well. Second, three possibilities occur to me about the `ndsz` problem: it is stiff, a false singularity has developed numerically, or it has a real singularity. Potential remedies for the first two: `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` or setting `WorkingPrecision` higher resp. An actual singularity may arise from a coding error or it may be a real feature. Try plotting the solution to see.

Comment: The coefficient sizes may add to the problems. You can play with their scal to see if it is a numerical issue. (Maybe make them all equal to 1 and integrate from 0 to 1 just to check the numerics.)

Comment: Michael E2, Thank you very much for your answer. Yes my system of ODE is quite tough and it is just the beginning of a more complex model. The program works perfect thank's to your advices. Now I do have a last question. How can I run once and again my program if i do want to increase a parameter (ds) till certain value? Then I would like to sum all the results up. I have try to do something with Manipulate, at least to see whether I can see any change. But Manipulate does not work with NDSolve. Thank you in advance. Regards.

Comment: @RKdifferential You're welcome. To create a list of solutions for `ds = 0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.`, you could use `Table` like this: `solutionlist = Table[NDSolve[...], {ds, 0, 1 0.1}]`.  You could then add the results.  You could also look up `ParametricNDSolve`, which returns a `ParametricFunction` that sets up and solves the ODE for each value of `ds` you pass to it.

Comment: Michael E2, Thank you very much. Without your help, my scientific contribution would have been much difficult. I am looking forward to help you or be helped by you again. Have a nice time.

Comment: By the way, how can I check the quality of my integration? When I will use again in future Method->"RungeKutta" I would like to check it. Do you know how to do it?